# Internet explorer spilling content out of container

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to make a bar that will show up on top of sites that belong to company I work for.

I first developed it for firefox and then came in horror when saw it in IE. It's completely broken.

The bottom line problem is how to make IE spill it's content when it's height is set?

Is there a fix for this, or should I take a different approach?

Here is the code for my current bar:

```
#rurbar{
font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
background:#111111;
color:#FFFFFF;
border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
position:absolute;
height:25px;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
overflow:visible;
}
```

I have some dropdown menus in this bar so I can't use overflow:hidden.

Comment: Do you have to set a height, or can you just let the content overflow naturally?

Comment: If it doesn't work in IE8 it's the code where the problem lies.

Comment: I would gladly leave it as-is, but this bar is something like Blogger bar, so if it's messed up then all sites are messed up. I have tried max-height. It must have height of 25 pixels.

Comment: Spill content where? What does the content look like? Can you post a link?

Comment: yeah can you post a minimal version of the code on jsbin.com or let us have a link where we can see the problem

Answer (score 1):

I've been testing your CSS in IE8, and it behaves in the exact same way as Firefox does. That is; the contents of a *#rurbar* div who's content exceeds the given height flows over the bottom of the div, but the div remains the same.

With one exception. When the page is rendered in quirks-mode, the div will stretch.
Is the document being rendered in Quirks-mode? - To find out, press F12 in IE8 and look for the 'Document Mode'. You can change it to one of the Standard modes and see if it changes anything.

If this is the problem, then you will have to validate the HTML, so that IE won't bug out and enter Quirks-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that you specify a DOCTYPE at the top of your page, i've come across some CSS/JS oddities by forgetting this.